# JQuery - Add an onmouseover attribute to an input element where type equals image

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to add an onmouseover attribute to an input element where type equals image?

I have created the following code but it does not add the attribute.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input").each(function(i) {
                if (this.src.indexOf('/images/icons/thumbs.png') != -1) {
                    $(this).attr({ onmouseover: "images/icons/thumbsover.png" });
                    $(this).attr({ onmouseout: "images/icons/thumbsout.png" });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: 74 rep and a gold badge, I'm jealous!

Comment: It was all down to my daily visits on my iPod touch ;->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here some code that will give you the desired effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input:image[src$=thumbs.png]").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/icons/thumbsover.png")
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr("src", "images/icons/thumbsout.png")    
    });
});
```

PS. I would try and achieve the efect using pure CSS

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding the `onmouseover` attribute.

The `onmouseover` attribute is used in HTML to provide Javascript code that executes when the mouse moves over the element.

In jQuery, you should use the [event methods](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) instead.

You actually want to write the following:

```
$(":image[src='/images/icons/thumbs.png']").hover(
    function() { this.src = 'images/icons/thumbsover.png' },
    function() { this.src = 'images/icons/thumbsout.png' }
);
```

For more information, read about [selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Comment: In case you were wondering, `:image` matches inputs, not `img` elements.

Comment: The code above will not work for me unless I change it to: (note the src$) $(":image[src$='/images/icons/thumbs.png']").hover(

Answer (score 1):

Yep, very easy indeed with selectors:

```
$('input[type=image]').mouseover(function(){
    ...
}).mouseout(function(){
    ...
});
```

in this case, it seems you want to change the background image:

```
$('input:image[src=/images/icons/thumbs.png]').hover(function(){
    //Mouse Over
    $(this).attr('src','mouseoverimage.gif');
},
function(){
    //Mouse Out
    $(this).attr('src','mouseoutimage.gif');
});
```

Comment: You should use the `:image` selector.  Also, he's only applying this to a specific `src`.

Answer (score 1):

See jQuery's Selectors/[Attribute documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue) for more information.

```
$("input[type='image']").hover(
  function () {
    //mouseover
  },
  function () {
    // mouseout
  }
);
```

Comment: You should use the `:image` selector.  Also, he's only applying this to a specific `src`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the source of the image when the user hovers it? Then try the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input").each(function(i) {
            if (this.src.indexOf('/images/icons/thumbs.png') != -1) {
                $(this).hover(
                  function(){ $(this).attr("src", "images/icons/thumbsover.png");},
                  function(){ $(this).attr("src", "images/icons/thumbsout.png");}
                );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```